# Как правильнее реализовать промежуток времени в одном input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее реализовать выбор промежутка времени в 1 input (например: 17:00 - 23:54). Сейчас есть такой вариант реализации:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLvxxa

```
var maskBehavior = function (val) {
  if(val.indexOf('-') > -1){
    values = val.split(" - "); 
    val1 = values[0].split(':'); 
    val2 = values[1].split(':');
    time1 = getMaskInputTime(val1[0]);
    time2 = getMaskInputTime(val2[0]);
  } else {
    val = val.split(":");
    time1 = getMaskInputTime(val[0]);
    time2 = "H0:M0";
  }
  return time1 + ' - ' + time2;
}
spOptions = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
    field.mask(maskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
  },
  translation: {
    'H': { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false },
    'Z': { pattern: /[0-3]/, optional: false },
    'M': { pattern: /[0-5]/, optional: false}
  }
};

function getMaskInputTime(val){
  return (parseInt(val) > 19)?  "HZ:M0" : "H0:M0";
}

$('#ggg').mask(maskBehavior, spOptions);
```

Comment: вполне приемлемый вариант. В одном инпуте в принцпе сделать промежуток без проверки js не выйдет. Более логичный подход - это два  `<input type="time">`, тогда можно обойтись без js, просто выставляешь в разных инпутах время от и время до.

Comment: к сожалению нужен 1...

Comment: любопытства ради - что за задача такая что нужно исключительно одним?)

Answer (score 0):

Только если вручную вводить, то валидация не действует и еще для минут не действует.

Как по мне самым хорошим вариантом было бы отображения ошибки если зашел за min или max. Также если есть ошибка в поле, то можно не отправлять форму.

```js
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const value = target.value
  
  let error = ''
  if (target.getAttribute('min') > value) 
    error = 'Значение меньше нормы'
  else if (target.getAttribute('max') < value)
    error = 'Значение больше нормы'
    
  document.querySelector(`.error[data-input="${target.id}"]`).textContent = error
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="time" min="17:00" max="23:54" required />
<span class="error" data-input="myInput"></span>
```

Узнал что есть более удобный вариант валидации, но на нем не настроишь текст ошибки и не понятно можно ли получить статус валидности в JS.

```css
input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="time" min="17:00" max="23:54" required />
<span class="error"></span>
```

И вообще даже IE не поддерживает time. Кароче, говорят веб так быстро развивается, а без библиотек на обычном хтмл очень не удобно писать.